# Ubuntu desktop 12.04 and virtualbox - is it possible to set mobile resolution ? ( e.g. 1440x2560 )

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualbox, xorg, display-resolution

I installed ubuntu desktop 12.04 with guest additions on virtualbox. 
I try to set resolution with custom /etc/X11/xorg.conf config.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver     "vboxvideo"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1440x2560"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**The problem is the following**:
Ubuntu allows me to set resolution like "2560x1440", but does not accept resolution like "1440x2560".

It is possible to "hack" this?
Thank you.

Comment: Can't you use the graphical settings to rotate the screen?

Comment: @Zacharee1 in display settions there is only one "rotaion" option - "normal".

Comment: hmm. Have you checked VirtualBox's settings? I haven't used it much, but I know that VMWare has a menu where you set resolutions for the virtual machine. You may have to do that somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem)

New xorg.conf:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Device0"
    Driver     "vboxvideo"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VGA-0"
    Modeline "1440x2560_60.00"  318.00  1440 1568 1720 2000  2560 2563 2573 2651 -hsync +vsync
    Option "PreferredMode" "1440x2560_60.00"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Device0"
    Monitor    "VGA-0"
    DefaultDepth 24
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes "1440x2560_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Also notice that Monitor Identifier changed from "Monitor0" to "VGA-0".
If i don't use identifier "VGA-0" -> config does not work.